# "Filtrado" se refere ao que passou pelo filtro, o que foi bloqueado ou simplesmente algo que participou do processo?

Tags: significado

Quando se diz algo como "itens filtrados", o que foi retido (o que interessa, o objetivo) é o que teria passado através do filtro ou o que seria bloqueado (não passou)?

Isso também acontece com outras palavas parecidas, como "peneirado" e "coado".

Procurei nos dicionários, mas não deixam claro se é o que fica ou o que passa, parece ser apenas algo que "sofreu" uma filtragem, mas sem especificar. Porém não tenho certeza.

Comment: Assim sem pesquisar nada diria que é o que passou pelo filtro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Filtrar* tem estes dois significados (entre outros, [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/filtrar)):

> **1.** Fazer passar ou passar por um filtro [td. : *Filtrar a água*] [int. : *A água ainda não filtrou.*]
>   **2.** Impedir que passe inteira ou parcialmente [td. : *Filtrar raios solares*]

Portanto se qualquer foi filtrada, podemos tanto:

1. estar a falar de uma massa que passa por um filtro, referindo a massa antes de esta passar pelo filtro (*esta água **vai ser filtrada***), ou depois de passar (*esta água **foi filtrada***),
2. como podemos estar a falar de uma massa que foi bloqueada pelo filtro (*as impurezas da água **foram filtradas***). Exemplo do [corpus TODOS da Linguateca](http://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/corpus.php?corpus=TODOS): *São micro-organismos **filtrados** na [es]tação de tratamento, mas que libertam produtos «aromáticos voláteis» que dão «o cheiro e sabor à água».*

Falar de *itens filtrados* parece-me de facto ambíguo, porque aí só o contexto poderá esclarecer se devemos entender *itens* como: 1) os itens vistos como um todo (a coleção), 2) os itens que passaram o filtro e 3) os itens que não passaram o filtro.

Por este mesmo motivo, não gosto de que, em programação, funções de filtragem de coleções de ordem superior sejam chamadas de *filter* (o que significa devolver o valor de verdade na função passada?). *Mathematica* chama-lhe [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html), o que na minha opinião é menos ambíguo.

Comment: Não me parece que o Aulete legitime *impurezas filtradas*: o que se faz passar ou passa pelo filtro é a água. Mas por outro lado também não me parece que um construção esteja incorreta só por determinada aceção não constar do dicionário.

Comment: @Jacinto O que passa pelo filtro são também as impurezas (que são retidas pelo filtro). Não percebo por que achas que «impedir que passe inteira ou parcialmente» não legitima esse uso. Outro exemplo na mesma linha seria «filtrar _spam_».

Comment: Realmente, acho que o problema está na ambiguidade dessas palavras, dependendo assim do contexto pra se saber do que se refere. Exemplo: "leite coado" é um leite sem nada além de leite (sem nata, por exemplo), ou seja, o que passou através do filtro. Já "nata coada" se refere à nata que foi bloqueada pelo coador. Agora, coisas mais abstratas como "lista de resultados filtrados" depende de uma breve explicação sobre o que significa "filtrado".

Comment: @Artefacto, não creio que o sentido 2 do Aulete se aplique a impurezas e àgua, mas a luz (vê também *filtrado*); o Houaiss acrescenta som. No sentido 1 o *por* significa *através de*. Consulta também outros dicionários: à execeção do aulete todos os que vi restrigem explicitamente o que passa pelo filtro a fluidos ou fluidos e gases.

Comment: @Jacinto Quanto a 1, não duvido que _por_ significa _através de_. Mas não percebo o comentário de fluidos/gases/som, parece-me óbvio que quando muito esse é o significado original literal de _filtrar_, mas que a palavra se aplica, por extensão, a filtros não físicos, ou filtros que filtram sólidos. Quanto a 2., mesmo que tenhas razão na tua interpretação do significado do Aulete e que o que é filtrado nessa aceção é uma massa homogénea da qual parte é eliminada, é muito fácil encontrar exemplos como o que dou. Vou adicionar um.

Comment: Nesta altura dava jeito os verbos em português também se poderem combinar como em outras línguas: _filter out_ em inglês e _uitfilteren_ em holandês. Já agora, curioso que o [primeiro exemplo aqui](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/neerlandais-anglais/uitfiltert) era o que eu tinha em mente quando li o exemplo do Aulete (tipo _filtrar os raios UV_), não simplesmente uma cortina atenuar a intensidade da luz.

Comment: Eu concordo que se diz coisas como *impurezas filtradas, micro-organismos filtrados* (referindo-se à matéria retida pelo filtro), e nem isso me choca, mas parece-me que esse uso não está previsto no Aulete (nem nos outros dicionários que vi). A tua resposta cita o Aulete e depois continua com *portanto*, dando ideia que esse uso está previsto no Aulete; quando me parece que é antes um desenvolvimento que o Aulete ainda não acompanhou.

Answer (score 4):

Penso que em língua portuguesa corrente não existem palavras específicas derivadas de filtro (ou de peneira ou coar) para referir todos  os diversos elementos participantes no processo,tanto quanto sei.

Quando de diz filtrado penso que geralmente diz respeito a algo que participou no processo sem especificar que tipo de interveniente.

- Filtragem: processo de filtrar
- Filtrante/Filtro: aquele que filtra, ou retém
- Filtrado: Retenção,  o que ficou retido no filtro, o que foi retirado.
- Filtrado: Elemento a ser submetido a filtragem
- Filtrado: Elemento que foi submetido a filtragem
- Filtrado: Elementos resultantes da filtragem, o que passou no filtro

Pode igualmente referir se ao objectivo, o que se pretende obter, ou aos indesejáveis, o que se pretende descartar.

Comment: que participou no processo? O que passou pelo processo??

Comment: Processo de filtragem